# How to do Weierstrass-transform in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, computational-physics, discretization, quantum-mechanics

I have a diagonalization problem. I have the eigenstates correctly, and I want to do a Gaussian-smearing (Weierstrass-transform) on them. So I have the wave functions ($\Psi$), and the continuous equation:

$$\zeta(x)=\int \mathrm{d} x' g_{\sigma_x}\left(x-x'\right)\left|\Psi(x')\right|^2,$$

where $g_{\sigma_x}$ is a normal distribution.

I do not know, how to do this with discrete vectors in MATLAB, i.e., $|\Psi|^2, \zeta \in \mathbb{C}^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the convolution between two functions $f = |\Psi|^2$ and $g = g_{\sigma_x}(x)$, $h = (f * g)(x)$.

You can compute the Fourier transform of $h$, to get

$$\mathcal{F}\{h\} = \mathcal{F}\lbrace f\rbrace \mathcal{F}\lbrace g\rbrace\, ,$$

and then, just compute the inverse Fourier transform to obtain what you want

$$ h = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\lbrace\mathcal{F}\lbrace f \rbrace \mathcal{F}\lbrace g\rbrace\rbrace\, .$$

To do that in MATLAB, you need to sample your functions over your domain and use the Fast Fourier Transform instead. Maybe, MATLAB already has something like [`fftconvolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html#scipy.signal.fftconvolve).

Comment: Thanks, I think this has to work. Now I have problem only with normalization. $\sum_n \zeta(n)$ has to be one.

Comment: @Zsombor, you can divide by the norm of it.