# Convolution in Python

Tags: python, integral-equations, convolution

I have an integral of a convolution between two functions. How can I calculate this in Python? It is a continuum convolution.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can use [`convolve()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html) from [`scipy.signal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html). As mentioned in [a previous question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/32782/9667), you can take advantage that the Fourier Transform of a convolution represents a product.

Comment: Do you have any material that explain this things better? I will be gratefull! Btw, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @BrendaPinheiro, sadly I don't. But you might want to check Wikipedia's article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what kind of integral transform you are looking at.

Your comments suggest that you are looking at a Fourier transform specifically, so I would recommend the [FFT implementation of NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html). Using this approach you can also tackle Laplace transforms.

For the most general case you will have to evaluate your convolution using a brute force [numerical quadrature](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quadrature.html) appropriate for the type of integral you are trying to evaluate.